# Problem installing Kivy on PyCharm, windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, kivy

I am trying to install the Kivy package on Pycharm and for some reason it is giving me an error. Note its not from the pip, it works for other packages and it is updated. The reason why I am asking for help is because I dont understand the interpreters commands and errors so I would love some help.
Thanks, I appreciate all the help I can get :)

The commad that I am using is -> pip install kivy

This is the given error

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\frank\pycharmprojects\python1\venv\scripts\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Frank\\AppData\\Lo
cal\\Temp\\pip-install-vr4dy_sq\\kivy\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Frank\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-vr4dy_sq\\kivy\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(token
ize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base
 'C:\Users\Frank\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-j7rvr3va'
         cwd: C:\Users\Frank\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-vr4dy_sq\kivy\
    Complete output (395 lines):
    WARNING: Skipping page https://github.com/kivy-garden/garden/archive/master.zip because the HEAD request got Content-Type: application/zip.The only supported Con
tent-Type is text/html
      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
       command: 'c:\users\frank\pycharmprojects\python1\venv\scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Frank\\AppDat
a\\Local\\Temp\\pip-wheel-4p5fq9jt\\cython\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Frank\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-wheel-4p5fq9jt\\cython\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(
tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d
 'C:\Users\Frank\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-yf76rw9s'
           cwd: C:\Users\Frank\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-4p5fq9jt\cython\
      Complete output (321 lines):
      Unable to find pgen, not compiling formal grammar.
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
      copying cython.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython
      copying Cython\CodeWriter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython
      copying Cython\Coverage.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython
      copying Cython\Debugging.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython
      copying Cython\Shadow.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython
      copying Cython\StringIOTree.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython
      copying Cython\TestUtils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython
      copying Cython\Utils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython
      copying Cython\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Build
      copying Cython\Build\BuildExecutable.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Build
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\exc.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\float.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\function.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\getargs.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\instance.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\int.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\iterator.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\list.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\long.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\longintrepr.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\mapping.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\mem.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\method.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\module.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\number.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\object.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\oldbuffer.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\pycapsule.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\pylifecycle.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\pystate.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\pythread.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\ref.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\sequence.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\set.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\slice.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\string.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\tuple.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\type.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\unicode.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\version.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\weakref.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\cpython
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_bool.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_buffer.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_bytes.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_cobject.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_complex.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_dict.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_exc.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_float.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_function.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_getargs.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_instance.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_int.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_iterator.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_list.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_long.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_mapping.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_mem.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_method.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_module.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_number.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_object.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_oldbuffer.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_pycapsule.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_ref.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_sequence.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_set.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_string.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_tuple.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_type.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_unicode.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_version.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_weakref.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\stdio.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\stdlib.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\stl.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\libc
      copying Cython\Includes\libc\errno.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\libc
      copying Cython\Includes\libc\float.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\libc
      copying Cython\Includes\libc\limits.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\libc
      copying Cython\Includes\libc\locale.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\libc
      copying Cython\Includes\libc\math.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\libc
      copying Cython\Includes\libc\setjmp.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\libc
      copying Cython\Includes\libc\signal.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\libc
      copying Cython\Includes\libc\stddef.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\libc
      copying Cython\Includes\libc\stdint.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\libc
      copying Cython\Includes\libc\stdio.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\libc
      copying Cython\Includes\libc\stdlib.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\libc
      copying Cython\Includes\libc\string.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\libc
      copying Cython\Includes\libc\time.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\libc
      copying Cython\Includes\libc\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\libc
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\libcpp
      copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\algorithm.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\libcpp
      copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\cast.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\libcpp
      copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\complex.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\libcpp
      copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\deque.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\libcpp
      copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\forward_list.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\libcpp
      copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\functional.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\libcpp
      copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\iterator.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\libcpp
      copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\limits.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\libcpp
      copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\list.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\libcpp
      copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\map.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\libcpp
      copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\memory.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\libcpp
      copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\pair.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\libcpp
      copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\queue.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\libcpp
      copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\set.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\libcpp
      copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\stack.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\libcpp
      copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\string.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\libcpp
      copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\typeindex.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\libcpp
      copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\typeinfo.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\libcpp
      copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\unordered_map.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\libcpp
      copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\unordered_set.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\libcpp
      copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\utility.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\libcpp
      copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\vector.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\libcpp
      copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\libcpp
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\numpy
      copying Cython\Includes\numpy\math.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\numpy
      copying Cython\Includes\numpy\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\numpy
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\posix
      copying Cython\Includes\posix\dlfcn.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\posix
      copying Cython\Includes\posix\fcntl.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\posix
      copying Cython\Includes\posix\ioctl.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\posix
      copying Cython\Includes\posix\mman.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\posix
      copying Cython\Includes\posix\resource.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\posix
      copying Cython\Includes\posix\select.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\posix
      copying Cython\Includes\posix\signal.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\posix
      copying Cython\Includes\posix\stat.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\posix
      copying Cython\Includes\posix\stdio.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\posix
      copying Cython\Includes\posix\stdlib.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\posix
      copying Cython\Includes\posix\strings.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\posix
      copying Cython\Includes\posix\time.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\posix
      copying Cython\Includes\posix\types.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\posix
      copying Cython\Includes\posix\unistd.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\posix
      copying Cython\Includes\posix\wait.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\posix
      copying Cython\Includes\posix\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Includes\posix
      copying Cython\Compiler\Code.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\FlowControl.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\ParseTreeTransforms.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\Parsing.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\Scanning.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\Visitor.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Runtime\refnanny.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Runtime
      copying Cython\Debugger\Tests\codefile -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Debugger\Tests
      copying Cython\Debugger\Tests\cfuncs.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Debugger\Tests
      copying Cython\Plex\Actions.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Plex
      copying Cython\Plex\Scanners.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Plex
      copying Cython\Utility\CConvert.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\CpdefEnums.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\CppConvert.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\MemoryView.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\TestCythonScope.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\TestCyUtilityLoader.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\AsyncGen.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\Buffer.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\Builtins.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\Capsule.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\CMath.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\CommonStructures.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\Complex.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\Coroutine.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\CythonFunction.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\Embed.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\Exceptions.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\ExtensionTypes.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\FunctionArguments.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\ImportExport.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\MemoryView_C.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\ModuleSetupCode.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\ObjectHandling.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\Optimize.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\Overflow.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\Printing.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\Profile.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\StringTools.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\TestUtilityLoader.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\TypeConversion.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\arrayarray.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\CppSupport.cpp -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Cython\Utility
      running build_ext
      building 'Cython.Plex.Scanners' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      ----------------------------------------
      ERROR: Failed building wheel for cython
    ERROR: Failed to build one or more wheels
     Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "c:\users\frank\pycharmprojects\python1\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\installer.py", line 126, in fetch_build_egg
         subprocess.check_call(cmd)
       File "C:\Users\Frank\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 373, in check_call
         raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
     subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['c:\\users\\frank\\pycharmprojects\\python1\\venv\\scripts\\python.exe', '-m', 'pip', '--disable-pip-version-check', 'w
heel', '--no-deps', '-w', 'C:\\Users\\Frank\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmp9en8uo5g', '--quiet', '--find-links', 'https://github.com/kivy-garden/garden/archive/master.zip
', 'cython!=0.27,!=0.27.2,<=0.29.10,>=0.24']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
    
     The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
    
     Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
       File "C:\Users\Frank\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-vr4dy_sq\kivy\setup.py", line 1073, in <module>
         setup(
       File "c:\users\frank\pycharmprojects\python1\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 152, in setup
         _install_setup_requires(attrs)
       File "c:\users\frank\pycharmprojects\python1\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 147, in _install_setup_requires
         dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
       File "c:\users\frank\pycharmprojects\python1\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 673, in fetch_build_eggs
         resolved_dists = pkg_resources.working_set.resolve(
       File "c:\users\frank\pycharmprojects\python1\venv\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 764, in resolve
         dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(
       File "c:\users\frank\pycharmprojects\python1\venv\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1049, in best_match
         return self.obtain(req, installer)
       File "c:\users\frank\pycharmprojects\python1\venv\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1061, in obtain
         return installer(requirement)
       File "c:\users\frank\pycharmprojects\python1\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 732, in fetch_build_egg
         return fetch_build_egg(self, req)
       File "c:\users\frank\pycharmprojects\python1\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\installer.py", line 128, in fetch_build_egg
         raise DistutilsError(str(e)) from e
     distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Command '['c:\\users\\frank\\pycharmprojects\\python1\\venv\\scripts\\python.exe', '-m', 'pip', '--disable-pip-version-check',
'wheel', '--no-deps', '-w', 'C:\\Users\\Frank\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmp9en8uo5g', '--quiet', '--find-links', 'https://github.com/kivy-garden/garden/archive/master.z
ip', 'cython!=0.27,!=0.27.2,<=0.29.10,>=0.24']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
    Using setuptools
    User distribution detected, avoid portable command.
    Using this graphics system: OpenGL
    WARNING: A problem occurred while running pkg-config --libs --cflags gstreamer-1.0 (code 1)
    
    b"'pkg-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n"
    
    WARNING: A problem occurred while running pkg-config --libs --cflags gstreamer-1.0 (code 1)
    
    b"'pkg-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n"
    
    WARNING: A problem occurred while running pkg-config --libs --cflags sdl2 SDL2_ttf SDL2_image SDL2_mixer (code 1)
    
    b"'pkg-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n"
    
    ERROR: Dependency for context.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for compiler.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for context_instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for fbo.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for gl_instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for opengl.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for opengl_utils.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for shader.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for stencil_instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for scissor_instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for texture.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for vbo.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for vertex.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for vertex_instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for cgl.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for cgl_mock.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for cgl_gl.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for cgl_glew.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for cgl_sdl2.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for svg.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are my experience with installing kivy:

- Make sure you don't use python version 3.9
- pip install kivy - does not work

create new project using Virtualenv and using python 3.7 (of course other versions can also work except 3.9)

[image]

then simply create requirements.txt file within root of your project if not yet exist and include kivy

Pycharm automatically asks if you want to install requirements.

Finally, verify

```
import kivy
print(kivy.__version__)
```

output:

```
C:\Users\lww\PycharmProjects\kivyproject\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/lww/PycharmProjects/kivyproject/ver.py
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\lww\.kivy\logs\kivy_20-11-14_47.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.11.1
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "C:\Users\lww\PycharmProjects\kivyproject\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.7.4 (tags/v3.7.4:e09359112e, Jul  8 2019, 20:34:20) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "C:\Users\lww\PycharmProjects\kivyproject\venv\Scripts\python.exe"

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: It did install kivy. But it is not working it is giving me this error:

Comment: [INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\Frank\.kivy\logs\kivy_20-11-14_38.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.11.1
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "C:\Users\Frank\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.7.9 (tags/v3.7.9:13c94747c7, Aug 17 2020, 18:58:18) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "C:\Users\Frank\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Scripts\python.exe"
1.11.1

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: The message in red are not errors, they are INFO messages. you have installed correctly kivy version 1.11.1. You can start from here.  doc ---> https://kivy.org/doc/stable/installation/installation-windows.html

Comment: go to terminal tab in pycharm and install additionally:  python -m pip install docutils pygments pypiwin32 kivy.deps.sdl2 kivy.deps.glew  and then run hello world program from here https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/basic.html. it should work

Comment: IT FINALLY WORKED ! Thanks